# Rails Devise confirmable don't redirect to confirmations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am running Rails 5.1 with Devise 4.2.1.

I have configured Devise confirmable:
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
:recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

I have set the routes:
devise_for :users

I have generated views, and customized the sign up and confirmation.

I have also generated controllers, but not customized these, and don't refer to them in routes.

I have set authendicate user in my App Controller:
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #Login user
  before_action :authenticate_user!

When a user signs up he is redirected to sign in and not to confirmations/new.html.erb

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That is the correct behavior. confirmation/new is for re-sending confirmation mail and you don't need that page after sign up since signup process itself sends a confirmation email. That new page should be visited only when user clicks 'Resend confirmation email' link.

Comment: Hi @Sajan - is this correct behavior?
It never tells the user that the e-mail needs to be confirmed. It just redirects to login, with the alert - "You need to sign in ..."